# Building a lexer in C

Tags: c, implementation, finite-automata

I want to build a lexer in C and I am following the [dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_book), I can understand the state transitions but how to implement them?

Is there a better book?

The fact that I have to parse a string through a number of states so that I can tell whether the string is acceptable or not!

Comment: Which http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_book ?

Comment: You need to give us a bit more to go on. What aspect of implementing state transitions are you finding difficult?

Comment: y cant i build a lex??!!

Comment: "Is there a better book?" No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

G'day,

Assuming you mean The Dragon book on compiler design, I'd recommend having a look around [this page](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) on compiler tools.

The page itself is quite small but has links through to various excellent resources on lexical analysers.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 7):

You can implement simple state transitions with a single state variable, for example if you want to cycle through the states start->part1->part2->end then you can use an enum to keep track of the current state and use a switch statement for the code you want to run in each state.

```
enum state { start=1, part1, part2, end} mystate;

// ...
mystate = start;
do {
  switch (mystate) {
    case start:
      // ...
    case part1:
      // ...
    case part2:
      // ...
      if (part2_end_condition) mystate = end; // state++ will also work
      // Note you could also set the state back to part1 on some condition here
      // which creates a loop
      break;
  }
} while (mystate != end);
```

For more complex state transitions that depend on several variables, you should use tables/arrays like this:

```
var1    var2    var_end    next_state
0       0       0          state1
0       1       0          state2
1       0       0          state3
1       1       0          state4
-1      -1      1          state_end // -1 represents "doesn't matter" here
```

Comment: are state and mystate different variables?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. state is the name of the enum type, mystate is the only variable used here.

Answer (score 4):

There's more than one way to do it. Every regular expression corresponds directly to a simple structured program. For example, an expression for numbers could be this:

```
// regular expression
digit* [.digit*]
```

and the corresponding C code would be:

```
// corresponding code
while(DIGIT(*pc)) pc++;
if (*pc=='.'){
    pc++;
    while(DIGIT(*pc)) pc++;
}
```

The transition-table way of building lexers is, in my opinion, needlessly complicated, and obviously runs slower.

Comment: Any particular reason why you use *pc then pc[0] then *pc again?

Comment: @John. Fixed. I guess that's an accidental leftover from the case where I wanted to exclude the case of a stand-alone '.' by looking ahead. In other words, I should really wrap the whole thing in if(DIGIT(pc[0]) || (pc[0]=='.' && DIGIT(pc[1])))

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a more modern treatment than the dragon book(s) : Andrew W. Appel and Maia Ginsburg, Modern [Compiler Implementation in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521607655), Cambridge University Press, 2008.

Chapter 2 is focused on Lexical Analysis : Lexical tokens, Regular expressions, Finite automata; Nondeterministic Finite Automata; Lexical analyzer generators

Look at the [Table of Contents](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/toc.html)

Answer (score 0):

The program flex (a clone of lex) will create a lexer for you.

Given an input file with the lexer rules, it will produce a C file with an implementation of a lexer for those rules.

You can thus check the output of flex for how to write a lexer in C. That is, if you don't just want to use flex's lexer...

Comment: Also, Bison has a disclaimer that says that Bison-generated code can be used in non-GPL code.

Comment: updated (removed comments about GPL, my bad, sorry). Please don't call people silly. It was a little offended, but only at first. Bison did have issues with the generated code, glad to see they have added a disclaimer.